# Setup of a Constrained Optimization using Tensorflow, Pandas and Gradient Descent Optimizer

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, optimization, gradient-descent

I have an optimization problem where I have
`y_i = A_i^x*(Cr_i*c+T_i*t)`
where x,t,c are the variables to find in order to minimize the sum of y under certain constraints. I have my input data in a pandas dataframe where each row contains the values of A,Cr and T. The constraints are

`sum y_k over specific k's are no less than 1`

`sum y_m over specific m's where Cr is between 0.9-1.0 > sum y_t over specific t's where Cr is between 0-0.2`

Basically k,m,t here is a specific set of rows that I am filtering in during the setup of the problem. I am ok with a non global optima and just using ADAM optimizer within tensorflow.

Comment: What is the question? You should also provide some code - simple reproducible example.

Comment: The question is how to do this in tensorflow ? Specifically taking an input dataframe and transforming it into the objective function setup and constraint setup. I dont have the example code as I am not sure if this is possible in tensorflow.

Comment: I don't believe there's any way to do constrained optimization like this in tensorflow, and you'd probably be better off with something else. You can setup regularizers that will influence the loss passed to the optimizer, but I don't believe there's any way to enforce the constraints exactly.